# spring @PreAuthorize not working with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.webapp")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
       authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().
       antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").
       anyRequest().authenticated().
       and().
       formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().
       and().
       logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

}
}
```

when a request /admin/* comes in, it will verify if the user has admin role by calling "antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")." , but in my controller, it does not check if the user has other permissions with @PreAuthorize .

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "user" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user")
public class UserController {

static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

@Autowired
private RoleDAO roleDao;

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER_VIEW')")
public ModelAndView listUsers() {

    List<User> users = userDao.list();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/admin/user/user-list");
    model.addObject("users", users);
    if (model.getModel().get("user") == null) {
        model.getModel().put("user", new User());
    }
    this.loadRoles(model);
    return model;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your controller as a @PreAuthorize("denyall")?  If the preauth fails on the class, it's not going to even hit the method to attempt the preauth.

Comment: @JeffWang i removed denyall, but once the user with admin role log in without 'view_user' permission can still access url. i am sure preauthorized is not working. do you have any suggestions, thank you

Comment: From what I understand, the filter chain gets hit first, so the first rule evaluated is has role of Admin.  The second is the class level preauth, which is deny all.  The third, provided it gets through both, is the method level preauth, which is has role of user_view.  The fact that denyall is working means that preauth is working.  you may wish to check what roles the logged in user has in the listUsers method. (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())

Comment: @JeffWang denyall never worked. That is why I was saying that preauthorized never worked.

Comment: hmm, take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context  Although it's for 3.2.x, as far as I can tell, this particular FAQ is still applicable for 4.0.x

Comment: @JeffWang i tried those fix, but it does not work. :(

Comment: try putting the @PreAuthorize on your service layer (in your case in your DAO's) ...

Answer (score 4):

Normally, Spring Security becomes available in the root application context and Spring MVC beans are initialized in a child context.
Hence `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor` can't detect your controller beans because they live in a child context that is unknown to the root context.

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` or `<global-method-security>` has to be placed inside the same configuration class or xml file where your Spring MVC configration lives in order to enable `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize`.

Comment: Could you explain "*has to be placed inside the same configuration class or xml file where your Spring MVC configration lives*" in a little more detail. So where exactly to I have to put `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`?

Answer (score 1):

try to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` above your Security configuration class. It is works to me!