# Information on spring security annotations setting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

I have a web application and I want to use spring security in order to use the `@PreAuthorize` and `@Secured` annotations. Spring security is already implemented because in used for the Authentication part. So I have changed the xml with `<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />` to let spring handle `@Secured`. 
But, of course, this isn't all I must do because if I use `@Secured("denyAll")` to test the access on a method, let's call it `doSomething(Object j..)`, spring let me enter in the method and do what it does.

So searching in the web I saw that a `RoleVoter` must be used to implement the evaluation of what is inside of the annotation and I write the bean:

```
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

This bean is referenced in the http section with `<http pattern="/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">`

I clearly haven't done all the settings correctly but I cannot understand why and what I have not set.

EDIT: another information I need is why if I set `rolePrefix=""` the `hasRole("someRole")` does not work.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530536/spring-preauthorize-not-working-with-enableglobalmethodsecurityprepostenabled/33541625#33541625) can help you.

Comment: @ksokol thanks but in the project the global-method-etc is in the same context, and the classes that use security are in the same project