# Spring Security 4.0.4 @Secured not securing controller method call

Tags: spring-security

I get no exception, but the method marked with `@Secured` is called even when the user does not have the role specified. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-security` 1.3.5 in pom.xml but no Spring Boot autoconfig or other annotations.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/l"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured({"ROLE_TORZSMOD"})
public String list() {
    return "partnerList";
}
```

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Login info from debug log (ROLE_TORZSMOD is not in the list of authorities):

```
2016-06-17 09:55:10,378 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d78c39df:
Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@65812e3: Username: pappt; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; 
AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_BIZMOD; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7CE797647B43DEDCED00AF439F446FA1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_BIZMOD
```

Comment: try @PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_TORZSMOD'))

Comment: Tried hasAuthority because of this ROLE_ prefix mess. Same result. `<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_TORZSMOD')">` in JSP works. `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_TORZSMOD')")` doesn't. Also modified the annotation to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true, securedEnabled=true)`

Comment: tyr `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` and `hasRole` instead of hasAuthority

Comment: Tried, no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here: [spring @PreAuthorize not working with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530536/spring-preauthorize-not-working-with-enableglobalmethodsecurityprepostenabled)

Solution 1:

Move the annotation to another config class. Now both @Secured and @PreAuthorize works.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("name.gmail.nsomlai.sawmill.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true, securedEnabled=true)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Solution 2:

Leave the annotation where it is and add the security config class to the master config (not sure if this has any side effects but it works):

```
public class MasterConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }
    ...
}
```

Since it took me 3 days to implement a simple custom login page and URL security, I find it too risky to use Spring Security if I want to keep my deadlines. I will probably implement my own simple interceptor-based security. This thing is way too complicated for simple access control, with too many different versions, conflicting tutorials and a huge documentation.