# PreAuthorize does not work in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Why `@PreAuthorize` doesn't work? It does not throw any exceptions or errors. I have been struggling with this task for several days. I've tried many options but It doesn't work.

I will be very grateful to anyone who can help solve this [problem](https://github.com/romanych2021/TestPreAuthorize).

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    package com.testpreauthorize.security;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }





        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()


                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")

                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")

                    .and()

                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")

                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();

        }


    }
```

**HomeController.java**

```
    package com.testpreauthorize.controller;

    import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/")
        public String home () {
            return "/home";
        }


        @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
        @GetMapping(value = "/user")
        public String user () {
            return "/user";

        }


        @GetMapping(value = "/login")
        public String loginGet () {
            return "/login";
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/login")
        public String loginPost () {
            return "redirect:/user";
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530536/spring-preauthorize-not-working-with-enableglobalmethodsecurityprepostenabled

Comment: I would mark your comment as the best, but there is no such possibility on your comment. Or if you tell me how to mark your comment as the best one, I will. Comments are not the answer. If you provide an answer, then it will be possible to mark your answer as the best one. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you mean of course. Well I just searched and found a suitable answer at a past issue. I can't post it as an answer because it wouldn't be fair to do that. But you can just upvote by pressing the up arrow over the flag icon left to my comment to say that this comment was useful for you. Moreover it'd also be great if you upvote the correct answer at the past issue just to support the original solution.

Comment: I cannot vote because I need to have a higher rating.

Comment: Oh ok :) No problem then, sorry! I'm ok with it, just happy to help you ;)